# PHP: Convert array to indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Given I have an simple non-associative array `$values` of `SomeObject` items indexed by 0, 1, 2, etc.

What is the best syntax to construct associative array `$valuesByIndex` indexed by some value extracted from original items?

What I constructed is:

```
$key = function($val) {
   return $val->getSomeProperty();
};
$valuesByIndex = array_combine(array_map($key, $values), $values);
```

Which is pretty equals to:

```
$key = function($val) {
   return $val->getSomeProperty();
};

$valuesByIndex = [];
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $valuesByIndex[$key($val)] = $val;
}
```

Looking for pretty compact syntax.

Comment: `indexed by some value extracted from original items`  I have no idea what these are, some example data would be nice.  (if it's var_export )  If not I guess I can convert it....

Comment: There does not seem to a be a problem with your code. If you are looking for code review, then your question would be more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't like this `$val->getSomeProperty` it implies that `getSomeProperty` is known.  You could do something like `$valuesByIndex[$val->getSomeProperty()] = $val;` in the second example.  For example.  Or more likely `$valuesByIndex[$val->{foo}] = $val;`  etc. but the re-use of the variables `$valuesByIndex[$val->getSomeProperty()] = $val`  Makes little sense if `$val` is an object.  So you are setting some array item with the key of whatever `$val->getSomeProperty()` is to the object `$val`

Comment: Maybe that is right, but you see I have no way to know without any input/output data.  It just seems weird to me.

Comment: Anyway in your second example this is the same thing, that was my point `foreach ($values as $val) $valuesByIndex[$val->getSomeProperty()] = $val;`  In which case you can do `array_map(function($val) use (&$valuesByIndex){ $valuesByIndex[$val->getSomeProperty()] = $val; });`

Answer (score 0):

In this piece:

```
$key = function($val) {
   return $val->getSomeProperty();
};

$valuesByIndex = [];
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $valuesByIndex[$key($val)] = $val;
}
```

We can simply replace `$key($val)` with the contents of the function `$val->getSomeProperty()`  Which gives us

```
$valuesByIndex = [];
foreach ($values as $val) $valuesByIndex[$val->getSomeProperty()] = $val;
```

Because if the function returns this `$val->getSomeProperty()` we can just put it right in there and forgo that function completely.

However if this is from a DB call you may be able to use (in PDO) `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`  which takes the first column of the Select and makes it the top level key.